# Stop following the partner in Odoo 17 at creation time

Tags: odoo, xml-rpc

Tips on how to stop following a partner when it is created using php and ripcord?

I tried this:

```
$models = ripcord::client($url.'/xmlrpc/2/object');
$vals = array(
    'name' => 'Test', 
    'mail_create_nosubscribe' => true 
);

$partner_id = $models->execute_kw($db, $uid, $password, 'res.partner', 'create', array($vals));
```

but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

I'll use the example from the official documentation:

```php
$id = $models->execute_kw($db, $uid, $password, 'res.partner', 'create',
    array(array('name'=>"New Partner")));
```

The only expected argument for `create` is the set of values for creating a single record. These creation values should be formatted as a Python dictionary, and execute_kw anticipates Python arguments as a list. Consequently, an array of arrays is expected in PHP.

However, in certain methods, keyword arguments are also anticipated. To include or modify the context, you also can use keyword arguments in execute_kw. Odoo expects the context to be specified as a keyword, with a dictionary in Python or an array in PHP as its corresponding value.

```php
$id = $models->execute_kw($db, $uid, $password, 'res.partner', 'create',
    array(array('name'=>"New Partner")),
    array('context'=>array('mail_create_nosubscribe'=>true)));
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, your example works

Comment: On the same topic suggestions on how to remove followers of already existing partners (i.e. not at creation time)?

Comment: You need a list of partner IDs and then you can use `message_unsubscribe()` on every model with chatter. For example removing partner with ID 4 and 5 from sales order 345: `$models->execute_kw($db, $uid, $password, 'sale.order', 'message_unsubscribe', array(array(345), array(4, 5)))`. Didn't test it and im not in any means used to write PHP code ;-)

Comment: Your code work but for every call I have "TypeError: cannot marshal None unless allow_none is enabled".

Comment: Hm that's probably because of the returning value: `None`... so either try to enable `allow_none` or use another method of Odoo for unsubscribing :/